# Why does the buffer take up whole screen?

Tags: qgis, buffer

I am trying to create buffers around the Hurricane Sandy path I created in QGIS (points are lat/long).

I have both points from each day she was tracted and the line I created from it with Points2One.

When I go to make buffers around either the line or the points, the buffer takes up the whole screen. Its all just one color.

I have made buffers before but from data I did not create.

Right now all of my projections are set to WGS 84 EPSG 4326.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you are entering a value in miles or km (ie 10) but the projection is in geographic. The buffer tool will interpolate that as a 10 degree buffer. You will need to do one of two things:

1. translate your value to equal the buffer size in degrees, or,
2. reproject your data into a projection that is not geographic

Answer (score 1):

[Ryan is right](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/67776/115) - your buffer is in Degrees.

Right click your layer in QGIS and the click "Save as...". You have the opportunity to pick a CRS (Projection) for your data. Pick Selected CRS and then browse for an appropriate projection. I will assume you only have data covering the Eastern part of New York - If so perhaps you want EPSG:2260 (so you would have your data in feet). If you've tracked it from beginning to end you'll need something maybe in an equal area projection (?).