# Why does my buffer take up the entire screen?

Tags: qgis, buffer

I am using QGIS. I am aware there is a similar question here but the solution (changing the layer CRS) is not working for me. I cannot change my CRS as I am using information for the entire Asia-Pacific region. Is there another option to create a 1000 km buffer zone from all volcanoes in the region? It is currently projected as geographic coordinates, the default WGS:84.

Comment: What GIS are you using and which solutions have you tried? Are you working with point data? Please edit your question with this information so that we can assist you.

Comment: Is your data in a geographic or projected coordinate system? Also, what is the name of the coordinate system of your data?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that WGS 84 is a [geographic coordinate system vs. a projected coordinate system.](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/24705-Projected-Coordinate-System-vs.-Geographic-Coordinate-System) When you are telling QGIS that you want a 1000 km buffer, it is interpreting it as a 1000 degree buffer (an impossibly large amount). This is why it is covering your entire screen. To solve your problem you need to [project your data](http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/04/tutorial-working-with-projections-in.html) into a projected coordinate system, then do your buffer. ([See this link for further information.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67775/why-does-the-buffer-take-up-whole-screen))

Regarding which projection you should use, since you are doing distance buffering, a [hemisphere-wide projection that preserves distance](http://www.geo.hunter.cuny.edu/~jochen/gtech201/lectures/lec6concepts/map%20coordinate%20systems/how%20to%20choose%20a%20projection.htm) would be most appropriate. An azimuthal distance projection seems like it would work for you.

Comment: I understand that, but the projected coordinate systems appear to only be by state or country not regional, which is where I am having problems..

Comment: I am sure there are continental ones, ie Lambert Conformal Conic and the like

Comment: @lis I have edited my answer to address your issue.